# How to add two actions depending on 'type' attribute of element in XML using webdriver in c#

Tags: c#, xml, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have elements stored in a config.xml file as part of my project, currently I have a method to 'setData' which will find the element by the id and then set its value to the user input (using a webdriver instance called FireFoxBrowser)

I want to add a type attribute to the xml to differentiate between 'inputs' which will use the current code and 'button' to add code that will click anything with this type. How can I use webdriver to write this code?

```
    public void setData(string elementName, string elementValue)
    {
        XmlDocument docXml = null;
        try
        {
            docXml = new XmlDocument();

            string xmlPath = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName + @"\config.xml";
            docXml.Load(xmlPath);
            XmlNode nd = docXml.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(@"//page[@url='{0}']", FireFoxBrowser.Url.ToString()));
            if (nd != null)
            {
                var id = nd.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(@"element[@name='{0}']", elementName)).Attributes["id"].Value;

                FireFoxBrowser.FindElement(By.Id(id)).Clear();
                FireFoxBrowser.FindElement(By.Id(id)).SendKeys(elementValue);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (docXml != null)
                docXml = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following line of code which differentiates between type attribute set:

var id = nd.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(@"element[@name='{0}']", elementName)).Attributes["id"].Value;